# PHP MySQL how to properly store / escape string

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with string sting that contains `<br/>` or & , < and so on.

I am escaping it like this before I store them into DB

```
nl2br(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

However some times when I display stored results I get stuff like this

```
&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<br /><br />
```

can someone help / show me the best way to escape strings but preserve the break points and so on when I want to display it back on the screen.

thanks you

Comment: In PHP you have a suite of string sanitization functions and flagging types. It really depends on what you're storing. If your storing only <br>'s I'd suggest HTML entity and a string sanitize. As for XSS protection and filtering I'd suggest using a framework or library. For years I use code-igniter XSS_clean class when storing HTML/XML. For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you set the `double_encode` to `false`, otherwise already encoded strings will be encoded again, turning `&amp;` into `&amp;amp;`. Then when you go to display it after using `html_entity_decode`, it will appear as if it was still encoded.

Undesirable Result: http://ideone.com/uQxuAM

---

Using `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` will ensure this will not happen.

Then use `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` to display the value.

Demo: http://ideone.com/8Jo7YA

---

However, MySQL is fully capable of storing the decoded values in the database.

You never want to have htmlentities-encoded strings stored in your database. What happens when you want to generate a CSV or PDF, send an email, or anything which isn't HTML?

Aside from the fact you have to perform double the programming of encoding the data, increasing the amount of data in the database, then still need to decode the output, there are tons of articles online answering why you shouldn't.

So you should only ever need to encode the values for displaying the resulting data output in html.

Instead you should escape the input using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$string = '<a href="/path/to/file?a=b&foo=bar#baz">My Link</a>';
$sql = "INSERT INTO links (link)"
     . "VALUES(" . mysqli_real_escape_string($string) . "')";
```

or better yet use prepared statements

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO links (link) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $string);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then to format the output as a success message to display what was actually added to the database.

```
$html = "<div>Added Link: " . htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false) . "</div>";
```

Now there is no need to use `html_entity_decode` to have the html rendered in the browser.

Comment: Thanks I will try this today I accepted your answer as it provides in depth explanation and solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) might do this.

```
$string = '<a href="http://test.com>test</a><br/>test';
$encode = nl2br(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

echo html_entity_decode($encode, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

outputs original `$string`

```
<a href="http://test.com>test</a><br/>test
```

---

https://3v4l.org/qS5au

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. +1 however I accepted the other answer as it provides me with more detailed explanation.