# Escaping data for storage

Tags: php, sql-injection, codeigniter-4

I want to sanitize user data before passing it to the Codeigniter 4 model I am using. As warned in their manual that I still have to sanitize data before passing it to the query builder class despite it will be auto escape.
So how do I perfectly sanitize data especially when I am to store string with hyphen and apostrophe.
I am currently using the below code:

```
Function sanitize ($str) { 
$str = trim($str); 
$str = stripslashes($str);
$str = htmlspecialchars($str);
return $str; }
```

When I use this, it encoded some character before storing it which is not good if I want to retrieve the data.

And I am thinking about to use

```
$this->request->getPost('name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516681/php-mysql-how-to-properly-store-escape-string/37517842

Comment: You should check out esc function in CI4 : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?#esc

Comment: Sanitize for what? You tag this question [tag:sql-injection] but the functions you show have no relevance to sql injection defense. Just use query parameters.